# What is the recommended way to typing window or global properties?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In `index.html` import an external global script:

```
<script src="https://a.b.com/A.js"></script>
```

And then `window.A` was injected to global scope.

To use `A` like so:

```
const client = A.createClient(options)
client.foo()
```

What is the recommended way to write the declaration file for `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add global modifying declaration file:

```
export interface Client {
    foo(): void;
}

export interface A {
    createClient(options): Client;
}

declare global {
    interface Window {
        A: A;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
const client = window.A.createClient({});
client.foo();
```

More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html)

Comment: How to name the global modifying declaration file and where to place it? Does it should update the `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: You can call it `index.d.ts` (I don't think it is really matters). More info in [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html)

Comment: What make me confused is that where should I place the `index.d.ts` and how to inform TypeScript compiler to resolve it?

Is that `src/@types/window/index.d.ts`?

Comment: The placement doesn't matter as long as the file included in ts project (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). It is up to you to decide about the structure of your project